# jplayer doesn't play tracks (gives an NaN)

Tags: jplayer

i'm using jplayer on my website.
it works fine only on chrome.
on firefox and safari it doesn't play the tracks and gives an NaN on total time,
whil ein ie dives me an error:
a._getMovie() is null or is not a object

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i resolved on ie7 but even there i get the NaN on playtime.
any help?

Comment: Meybe gzip compression stops the browser from being able to retrieve the file metadata?

Answer (score 0):

Please look here (the question is similar, and the problem might be the same): [jQuery jPlayer can't be replayed after first run in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866471/jquery-jplayer-cant-be-replayed-after-first-run-in-safari/)