# jQuery jPlayer can't be replayed after first run in Safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, audio

After configuring and running jPlayer 2.0.0 in Firefox 3.6.13, where everthing runs smooth, the same code doesn't run in Safari 5.0.3. What i am doing is creating the jPlayer, listen for the "ended"-event to restart it. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loopplayer").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: "/static/audio/brokentech.mp3"});
        },
        swfPath: "/static/swf",
        supplied: "mp3",
        preload: true,
        });
    $("#loopplayer").bind($.jPlayer.event.ended, function(){
      $(this).jPlayer("play" );
     });
    });
```

Whats happening in Safari is: the progress bar shows NaN as length of the track, and it stops after running once. When i remove the event listener and reload the page, i can run the jPlayer once (again with NaN as tracklength), after it has run once i am not able to restart it. Anything wrong with my code or a bug in jP2?

Comment: Meybe the file is being served through gzip compression and it blocks the browser from being able to retrieve the file metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:

http://groups.google.com/group/jplayer/tree/browse_frm/month/2010-05/bb4306c1850108b1?rnum=71&_done=/group/jplayer/browse_frm/month/2010-05%3F

There are some mp3s that have problems with jPlayer due to the way files are served. The browser doesn't retrieve metadata correctly on gzipped response.

Comment: This one matches better, as i do not have that problem when serving just .ogg and .wav. But this is not related to gzip, as no compression is applied.

Comment: Hm, when using this from a local copy it works fine. Looks like you have been right about the serving too. Can this have other reasons than gzipping too? Is there a way to access the metadata, ie. downloading the complete file including the metadata?

Comment: To inspect headers, you can use a browser which shows http headers, such as Mozilla Firefox with the firebug extension (F12) or Google Chrome (right click anywhere -> "Inspect element" -> "Resources" tab. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to re-set the media in the `ended` event.

This works in Safari 7.0, which only plays the sound once and mutes for subsequent replay attempts without the hack.

```
$(function() {
    $('#jp').jPlayer({
        ready: function() {
            // Set the media when jPlayer is ready.
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: "/audio/demo.mp3"});
        },
        ended: function() {
            // Do it again after it finishes playing.
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: "/audio/demo.mp3"});
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you give the swfpath as follow or use full domain path
{
        swfPath: "[http://localhost/jplayer/js/]",
        supplied: "webmv, ogv, m4v, oga, mp3"
}